# If correlation is a measure for linear terms what is a measure for quadratic terms

Tags: correlation, independence

I was thinking today this question on [correlation and dependence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) and I would like to know how do I measure quadratic terms of dependence say I don't have correlation between two sets.

Possible generalization for cubic terms would be nice as well.

Comment: Not in a position to post right now, but check out mutual information and redundancy. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_information

Comment: One wonders what exactly you might mean by "quadratic terms of dependence." Could you articulate your objective?

Comment: @whuber can I use just an examaple :) for set a (1,2,3,4), for set b(1,4,9,16) the measure to check for the quadratic terms would provide 1.

Comment: This helpful example exhibits an asymmetry between the variables: one is the square of the other.  The concept of "correlation," on the other hand, is *symmetric:* that is what distinguishes it from regression.  Although it is clear what a quadratic regression model, it is hard to conceive of a quadratic *correlation.* So are you really just asking about regression?

Comment: Well correlation matrix is symmetric, I would not say correlation is symmetric, why do you think correlation is symmetric and regression is not, I cannot understand that. For this example I would assume if I would have b(16,9,4,1) in reverse order I would get -1. You can easily square root the whole set b and check the correlation, but does it have some term as a measure I don't know so I am asking.

Comment: @whuber, there are few more glitches with this measure what I see now and haven't saw before say if the numbers of the second set are negative, but I think the question is still legit because I am asking not because I know, instead I am asking because I am not aware of.

Comment: If you were thinking on commutative low, like cor(a,b)=cor(b,a), for this measure of quadratic this will not work.

Comment: The asymmetry to which I refer is that when one variable $y$ depends quadratically on $x,$ then $x$ does *not* depend quadratically on $y.$  The matrix is irrelevant, because you cannot even define it until you have defined what you mean by a "quadratic correlation."

Comment: So you meant if the commutative low will work for this operation in other words. Well, no. Your questions were purifying. Thank you!